# isUnix for jenkins job dsl?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I use the isUnix function in my pipeline jobs, it would be nice if the jobs dsl also had this feature (I still need to use it for some things pipelines cant do). If not how do you check for windows or linux inside of a jenkins job dsl script?

Comment: Note that the Job DSL script will just _create_ Jenkins jobs. This creation step typically does not depend on the OS. Adding a `isUnix` condition in the DSL script will not have any effect on the jobs that were created. Are you sure this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job DSL script:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils

if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_UNIX || SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC) {
  println 'linux'
  job('jobname') {
    //job steps
  }
}
else {
  println 'windows'
}
```